# <tbody> causing validation issue

Tags: html, validation, html-table

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<table>
    <tbody>
    <?php echo $header; ?>
    <?php
    for ($i=1; $i<=14; $i++)
      {
      echo "
            <tr id=\"rq". $i. "\">
            <td class='qnum'>". $i . ".</td>
            <td class='qtext'>". $q[$i] . "</td>
            <td style='width:20px;'></td>";
      echo" <td colspan=2><div id='slider_". $i . "' class='shown' name='slider' style='width:374px;height:10px;display:block;background:white;border:1px solid #B3C6FF'></div></td>";

      echo" <td style='width:20px;'></td></tr>";
        }?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When I go to validate the code I get the following error:

> end tag for "tbody" which is not finished

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written a piece of software using PHP. When you run that piece of software, it will output some XHTML.

You need to validate the XHTML, not the PHP source code.

The tbody isn't finished because all the table rows are output by PHP. While you have the tags in the PHP source, they are inside a PI so won't be treated as tags.

Comment: you, sir, are a sage :-) I'd expect OP to already have been doing exacly that :-)

Comment: @Jan - thanks for the reply.  I'm using the WS3C validation service (which includes XHTML) and this is the only thing not validating.  It's nothing to do with the PHP as it is spitting out simple text.  Hence my confusion.

Comment: @Homer_J — What is "the WS3C validation service"? Are you conflating W3Schools (awful tutorial site) with the W3C (standards body)? If you validate the result of running the PHP in the question then there is no error that mentions `tbody`. If you try to validate the PHP itself, then you do get the error you described. Either you are showing us the wrong source code or you are wrong about validating the output instead of the PHP source.

Comment: @Homer_J, did this answer your question or not? Accepting the answer says “yes”, but your comment says otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you do not validate your PHP, you validate the HTML code *generated* by PHP instead. Also, make sure that the code generated by PHP is valid, as there are no un-closed tags, un-closed quotes. The exact fix to your problem cannot be determined without you giving us the exact HTML generated by your PHP code, as we are not aware what is the content of `$header`, to give you an example. So, if you need more information, edit your question and add the HTML code generated as well, but my advices should be enough by themselves to enable you fix your bug. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks - appreciated - will re-investigate.